# Dependency Injection with Umbraco services

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to scope `UmbracoCms.IMemberService` and `UmbracoCms.IScopeProvider` in the startup class of a web API that I have to connect to a Umbraco web project.

I'm a little green working with Umbraco, when I try to do the DI I get the message:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Umbraco.Cms.Core.Scoping.IScopeProvider' while attempting to activate 'UserRepository'.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is your Umbraco version?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who will need an answer. There is no way to consume umbraco services in a web api.

What i did was to create an `ApplicationDbContext` and the structure needed to get the data from the DB.